# Meteor Access Denied when calling google's Geocoder API

Tags: node.js, meteor, geocoding, google-geocoder

While calling geocode API of google maps, i am getting Access Denied. It strange since i can call LatLng and it works fine. What am i missing ? I also have my key and everything defined.

GoogleMaps.load({
      v: '3', 
      key: 'xyz key', 
      libraries: 'geometry,places'
    });

```
     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      geocoder.geocode({
        'address': '1234 street'
      }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          console.log(results[0].geometry.location);
        } else {
          console.log("some err " + results + " status " + status);
        }
      });
```

Comment: Can you see any error message in browser console after loading of Google Maps JavaScript API? Did you enable Geocoding API web service in your project?

Comment: No i dont see any error except "Request Denied"

Comment: What about Geocoding API in your project? Is it enabled?

Comment: Yes it is. i moved to different gelocation package aldeed:geocodor and its working for me not sure whats issue with using google geocoder api directly.